LuaLatex, Tikz and Strings in Plot
Before I start my real plot, I try smaller things I consider to use. Finally, I want to draw CPU register mapping similar as shown before here at StackExchange.
Anyway, here is my latex source:
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\directlua{%
    function randomHexByteStr()
        return string.format("%02X", math.random(0, 255))
    end
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{randomHexByte}{0}{%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
     \directlua{tex.print(randomHexByteStr())}%
   }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) { \pgfmathparse{ randomHexByte() }\pgfmathresult };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

My first problem is, that it compiles at CoCalc.com, but not locally here (Windows with VS Code and LaTeX Workshop using ubuntu docker image in devcontainer):
- unfinished string near «eof>. LaTeX [Line 1, Row 1]
- attempt to call a nil value (global 'randomHexByteStr') LaTeX [Zeile 1, Spalte 1]

As second, it doesn't give the expected result - I want to have the hex-number generated by the Lua function randomHexByteStr() resp. Pgf function randomHexByte inside the box. The number isn't shown.
Where are my faults and how to fix both errors?

% is a tex comment so Lua only sees return string.format("  hence the unfinished string error, use \@percentchar to get a % and use \makeatletter... \makeatother around the code

the link you give uses the luacode package which handles the % for you (although has some good and bad points, using \directlua is my usual preference) so the fact that it works is because it is different code not because it is running at cocalc.com


\directlua is interpreted as TeX before being passed to Lua, so % is a comment and you lose the rest of the expression. \@percentchar expands to a non-comment % so:
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\directlua{%
    function randomHexByteStr()
        return string.format("\@percentchar X", math.random(0, 255))
    end
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{randomHexByte}{0}{%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
     \directlua{tex.print(randomHexByteStr())}%
   }%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) { \pgfmathparse{ randomHexByte() }\pgfmathresult };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


To get the result printed It's easier just to call the Lua directly, the indirection via a pgf function doesn't help.

\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\directlua{%
    function randomHexByteStr()
        return string.format("\@percentchar X", math.random(0, 255))
    end
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0,0) { \directlua{tex.print(randomHexByteStr())}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

